# Custom UrlHelper method not being included

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, extension-methods

I made a custom helper that I was trying to include as available to all pages.

helper:

```
namespace project.CacheBreaker
{
 public static class CacheBreaker
 {
    public static void CacheBreak(
        this UrlHelper url, string contentPath)
    {
        url.Content(contentPath);
    }
 }
}
```

I tried to expose it from `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
 <pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="project.CacheBreaker"/>
  </namespaces>
 </pages>
</system.web>
```

I got an error while trying to access it in a view:

```
<script src="@Url.CacheBreak("~/Scripts/link.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

which stated:

```
"Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required
to service this request. Please review the following specific error details 
and modify your source code appropriately."
```

```
"Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' does not contain 
a definition for 'CacheBreak' and no extension method 'CacheBreak' accepting a 
first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

I thought I had taken all the necessary steps, why isn't this custom method available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But your UrlHelper doesn't return anything. It's void. You can't possibly call it with: `@Url.CacheBreak(...)`. If you want your helper to be used that way it should return an `IHtmlString` or a `string`:

```
public static string CacheBreak(this UrlHelper url, string contentPath)
{
    return url.Content(contentPath);
}
```

Oh and by the way having a helper that just wraps around `Url.Content` seems kinda useless, coz you could directly write:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/link.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also the wbe.config you are talking about in your question seems the wrong wbe.config. You know, there's a `~/web.config` and there's also a `~/Views/web.config` which are 2 completely different files. If you are using the Razor view engine you should define your namespace in the `~/Views/web.config` file:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />

        <add namespace="project.CacheBreaker"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: I was under the impression it would use the contextwriter to output from the base implementation of `Url.Content`

Comment: No, that's a wrong impression. If you want that to happen you will have to write directly to the view output stream. The Url.Content helper doesn't do that.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification. As for the simple wrapping, it has other implementation that I felt was not necessary to convey because all it does it conditionally append a `?version` to the contentPath.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Just worth mentioning it so that next time you ask a question on SO you show your real code.

Comment: The code is not implemented or I would show it. I was just testing the helper's access and came across the error. `@Url.Content` does return a `string`, not sure why I didn't properly observe that. Would there be any benefit in returning an `IHtmlString` here as opposed to just returning `string`?

Comment: The difference between returning an `IHtmlString` and `string` is that  if you return an `IHtmlString` the `@` Razor function will not HTML encode it, so it's up to you to do that HTML encoding in your helper to avoid XSS attacks. If you return a `string` then the `@` Razor function will safely HTML encode the output. All Html helpers return `IHtmlString` because they take care of HTML encoding internally. So it's really up to your specific implementation to choose the right type.

Comment: I thought to use the `~/web.config` file because I use various areas and didn't want to have to redefine the addition in each nested config file.

Comment: `~/web.config` is not used by Razor! If you have areas you will need to define a specific `~/Areas/MyAreaName/web.config` file.